# How do I set default timezone in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, timezone

So I have a system that is mostly finished, just ironing out some final bugs. We have an issue that the program seems to be permanently set in the New York timezone.

I have this line of code in both core.php and bootstrap.php:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Australia/Melbourne");
```

But the system keeps reporting that it is in America/NewYork.

Can anyone help me set the timezone to Australia Melbourne?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the `config/core.php` file of the app folder try the following with single quotes:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Melbourne');
```

Comment: Set timezone in App/Config/bootstrap.php (Cakephp 2.6+)

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Dublin');

Comment: had this problem with CakePHP 3 and adding date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Dublin'); t o the bootstrap file fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

You can add this in `config/core.php`:

```
Configure::write('Config.timezone', 'Europe/London');
```

Comment: for some reason this didn't work on cakePHP 2.x and `date_default_timezone_set()` worked as usual.

Comment: Although, I don't vote down, Not working yet, at least with CakePHP 2.6.0

Answer (score 3):

Set timezone in App/Config/bootstrap.php (Cakephp 2.6+)

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Dublin');
ini_set('date.timezone', 'Europe/Dublin');
//Configure::write('Config.timezone', 'Europe/Dublin');
```

Comment: For some reason setting timezone won't work in Configure::write() at all! Any Idea?

Answer (score 2):

As of CakePHP 3.x, the configuration for default timezone is found in config/bootstrap.php.

CakePHP uses the PHP timezone codes, which can be found in the PHP docs here: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

For example, a server in Los Angeles will be configured like this: `date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');`