# Am getting timezone error in cakephp

Tags: mysql, .htaccess, cakephp

am getting continue this error in cakephp even i ave set timezone in php.ini but it gives 500 internal server error

Warning: strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in /home1/allinal6/public_html/telecom/lib/Cake/Cache/CacheEngine.php on line 61

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That warning is unrelated to your 500 internal server error.  However, in order to remove that warning, as seen on [How do I set default timezone in cakephp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22625181/how-do-i-set-default-timezone-in-cakephp) go into /app/config/core.php and find the line that calls `date_default_timezone_set();` (normally commented out when you first download CakePHP.)  Uncomment it and add your desired timezone.